# Updating time and date by the second in Android

Tags: java, android

I want to display the time and date in a TextView in real time (updating it by the minute). Currently, I have this. Is this the best way of doing that, considering memory use and Android best practice? (note: `DateFormat` is `java.text.DateFormat`)

```
private Thread dtThread;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...
    getDateAndTime();
}

private void getDateAndTime() {
    dtThread = new Thread( new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            Log.d(TAG, "D/T thread started");
            while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
                try {
                    update();
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "D/T thread interrupted");
                }
            }
        }

        public void update() {
            runOnUiThread( new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Date d = new Date();
                    String time = DateFormat.getTimeInstance(DateFormat.MEDIUM).format(d);
                    String date = DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.LONG).format(d);

                    TextView timeView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textStartTime);
                    TextView dateView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textStartDate);
                    timeView.setText(time);
                    dateView.setText(date);
                }

            });
        }

    });

    dtThread.start();
}

protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    dtThread.interrupt();
    dtThread = null;
}

protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    getDateAndTime();
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would use a Runnable and post it with a delay to a Handler.

```
public class ClockActivity extends Activity {

    private SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm:ss");

    private TextView mClock;
    private boolean mActive;
    private final Handler mHandler;

    private final Runnable mRunnable = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            if (mActive) {
                if (mClock != null) {
                    mClock.setText(getTime());
                }
                mHandler.postDelayed(mRunnable, 1000);
            }
        }
    };

    public ClockActivity() {
        mHandler = new Handler();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        mClock = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.clock_textview);
        startClock();
    }

    private String getTime() {
        return sdf.format(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()));
    }

    private void startClock() {
        mActive = true;
        mHandler.post(mRunnable);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can probably use a handler to post updates to the UI Thread. check out this best practices for updating a timer

http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/timed-ui-updates.html

Answer (score 1):

Instead of designing your own timer to handle this I recommend using a broadcast reciever listing for this intent broadcastet sent every minut: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_TIME_TICK

If you would like example code for how to do this please let me know.

Comment: It doesn't seem like `ACTION_TIME_TICK` allows me to update by the second. In that regard, using a broadcast receiver seems to me like a Rube Goldberg way of doing this.

Comment: True, 'ACTION_TIME_TICK' is updated every minute, on the minute. But if you wish to update the textview to display the date and time to the minute, it should perform the task you need it to.