# get time and date in each button click android

Tags: java, android, datetime

I have this button that will generate time and date and set it as a child in a database tree, the problem is whenever I click buttons it generates the said time but the time is not changing,

for example i clicked on the button and it generates the time 12:27 Pm, and it will be recorded into the database, now i clicked the button again for the second time and it doesn't change still printing out the 12:27 Pm Instead 12:30 Pm.

the code looks like this

```
 btnadd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Integer num1 = Integer.parseInt(edt1.getText().toString());
            Integer num2 = Integer.parseInt(edt2.getText().toString());
            Integer result = num1+num2;
            String data = "Date Computed: " + Date + Hrs +"Result: "+ result;

            DateView.setText(data);

            HashMap<String, String> userMap = new HashMap<>();
            userMap.put("Add", data);


            rootNode = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
            reference = rootNode.getReference("Users").child("UserID").child(Date);
            reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                    if (snapshot.exists()){
                        maxid = (snapshot.getChildrenCount());
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

                }
            });

            reference.child("Transaction"+maxid).setValue(userMap);
        }
    });

    edt1 = findViewById(R.id.edt1);
    edt2 = findViewById(R.id.edt2);
    btnadd = findViewById(R.id.btnadd);
    btnmin = findViewById(R.id.btnmin);
    DateView = findViewById(R.id.DateView);
    calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd-yyyy");
    Date = simpleDateFormat.format(calendar.getTime());
    simpleHoursFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(" hh:mm:ss ");
    Hrs = simpleHoursFormat.format(calendar.getTime());
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Updating time and date by the second in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6400846/updating-time-and-date-by-the-second-in-android)

Comment: Can you share the code where you are initialised the `Date` and `Hrs` variables used in `String data`.  Issue is occurring maybe because you are not updating the Date and Hrs variables everytime btn is clicked.

Comment: @satya-p91 i edited my question, can you check it out?

Comment: You generate the date once--you need to do it in the click handier itself. It's a little hard to read the code, so I might be reading the nesting wrong. I'd also recommend sticking with Java naming conventions.

Comment: sorry but can you atleast provide me a sample code for this i'm new to android developing @DaveNewton

Comment: As an aside consider throwing away the long outmoded and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` and friends. See if you either can use [desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) or add [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) to your Android project, in order to use java.time, the modern Java date and time API. It is so much nicer to work with.

Comment: I see nothing in `onClick()` that would change `Date` and `Hrs` — which should be `date` and `hrs`, please use a small first letter in variable names. In any case, this would lead me to expect the behaviour that you also describe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi from the code it looks like you haven't updated your `Date` and `Time` in your `onClickListener`. The updated code should be like this :-

```
btnadd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // This will fetch your updated date and time 
            Date = simpleDateFormat.format(calendar.getTime());
            Hrs = simpleHoursFormat.format(calendar.getTime());
            Integer num1 = Integer.parseInt(edt1.getText().toString());
            // Rest of your code
```

Comment: @Jm25E Please accept and upvote this answer if it helps you so that others can find it easily.

Answer (score -1):

Try to use this

```
import java.util.Calendar
Date currentTime = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
```

Comment: hi can this make my every button click change my date and time?

Comment: Thanks for wanting to contribute. I fail to see where to insert it in the OP’s code for it to help.